# Redundant conformance of 'InboxTableViewController' to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'

Tags: ios, swift4

I have new in iOS developing and when i build my project its show me this error

> "Redundant conformance of 'InboxTableViewController' to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource"'

This is code

```
class InboxTableViewController: UITableViewController,
                                UITableViewDataSource,
                                UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    private let CARD_CELL        = "CardCell"
    private let VIEW_CARD_SEGUE  = "ViewCardSegue"
    private let EDIT_CARD_SEGUE  = "EditCardSegue"
    private let TAG_TITLE_LABEL  = 1
    private let TAG_DETAIL_LABEL = 2
    private let TAG_CANVAS       = 3

    private let agent = RenderingAgent()
    private var listeningForChangeEvents = false

    var cards: ArrayList {
        return DataUtility.AllCards
```

Answer (score 2):

By subclassing `UITableViewController` you already implement `UITableViewDataSource`, therefore listing it again causes this error. You just need this (no `UITableViewDataSource` there):

```
class InboxTableViewController: UITableViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
```

You can see in [official docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcontroller) of the `UITableViewController` in section `Conforms To` that it already conforms to `UITableViewDataSource`. Just add override to those `UITableViewDataSource` methods that you want to implement, so e.g.:

```
class InboxTableViewController: UITableViewController,
                                UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    private let CARD_CELL        = "CardCell"
    private let VIEW_CARD_SEGUE  = "ViewCardSegue"
    private let EDIT_CARD_SEGUE  = "EditCardSegue"
    private let TAG_TITLE_LABEL  = 1
    private let TAG_DETAIL_LABEL = 2
    private let TAG_CANVAS       = 3

    private let agent = RenderingAgent()
    private var listeningForChangeEvents = false

    var cards: ArrayList {
        return DataUtility.AllCards
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // implement
    }
```